# Objective C: Adding Loading View to View Controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, load

In my application, I require a loading screen for many of my pages.

How can I create a similar loading effect as seen in the screenshot below?

[image]

Comment: An alternative to using custom classes would be to simply create a UIActivityIndicatorView and throw it in a UIAlertView, for example, with your own text, title and button(s).

Comment: @highlycaffeinated, I have tried to create another viewcontroller and add it's view as a subview to the existing view whenever I am loading stuff, but it seems highly inefficient and confusing. I was also advised that add another view controller's view to an existing view controller is not a recommended approach

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Checkout MBProgressHUD: https://github.com/jk/MBProgressHUD or DSActivityView: http://www.dejal.com/developer/dsactivityview