# iPhone Loading Popup Scroll Down

Tags: iphone, objective-c

is there anyone knows a lib for creating a simple view that scroll down from the top of the screen for "Loading.." message?

Like http://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD but the view should scroll down when begins to loading and scroll up when finish.

Comment: Are you asking for an implementation of "Pull to Refresh"?

Comment: No. Imagine an UIButton. When you click it, from the top of the app window appear with a slideIn effect a popup which says "Loading..". When the loading is finished the popup "slideOut". Understood?

Comment: Sounds like a lot of custom view juggling that you're going to have to do yourself, mate. Sounds cool though; good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It might seem a little jarring to the user to scroll down and then back up.  It shifts the users view of the data down and then back up without user interaction ...

I would simply overlay the loading view ...

[Objective C: Adding Loading View to View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396567/objective-c-adding-loading-view-to-view-controllers)

Comment: bryanmac no because the data doesn't shift down and up. Only the little view. Like the new Apple notification system. You get it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the code here: [Simple Notifications for iPhone](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/macosxdev/120080/). Sorry for Russian, but the idea should be clear. You just need to add transition from the top of the page when notification label is shown.